# Bringing data from three tables to a single table based on Events

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables Emailsent, Emailopened and Emailclicked

```
EmailSent table
id| senteventtime 
1 . 2019-09-05 17:47:37.0
2 . 2019-09-03 10:34:20.0
3 . 2019-06-02 07:32:11.0
----------------
EmailOpen table
id| Openeventtime 
1 . 2019-09-05 17:50:21.0
2 . 2019-09-03 10:35:23.0
3 . 2019-06-02 07:43:10.0
----------------
Emailclick table
id| clickeventtime 
1 . 2019-09-05 17:52:24.0
2 . 2019-09-03 10:35:32.0
3 . 2019-06-02 07:43:16.0
```

I would like to combine these three tables to be in a single event level table like below with a custom column having the eventname.

```
id | Eventname | Eventdatetime
1 .   sent        2019-09-05 17:47:37.0
1 .  opened       2019-09-05 17:50:21.0
1 .   clicked     2019-09-05 17:52:24.0
2 .  sent         2019-09-03 10:34:20.0
2 .  opened       2019-09-03 10:35:23.0
2 .  clicked      2019-09-03 10:35:32.0
```

something like this.

I tried union all on the tables but didn't work. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` with proper ordering:

```
(
    SELECT id, 'sent' eventname, eventtime eventdatetime FROM EmailSent
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'opened', eventtime FROM EmailOpen
    UNION ALL SELECT id, 'clicked', eventtime FROM Emailclick
)
ORDER BY id, eventname DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Union` you could just create a text column although this isn't very dyanmic.

```
SELECT
    id,
    senteventtime as Event_datetime
    'Sent' as Event_name
FROM senteventtime

UNION 

SELECT
    id,
    openeventtime as Event_datetime
    'EmailOpen' as Event_name
FROM openeventtime

UION ....
```